# regarding converting the code into functional style in java

Tags: java

I have the below code , please advise how can i convert the below into functional style

```
for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry : delMap.entrySet())
{
  String abcId = entry.getKey();
  abcService.getsmartIds(abcId,enty.getValue());
}
```

I am new bie to the world of functional programming in java

Comment: Please advise us where you are struggling, your current question is very broadly phrased.

Comment: You are processing the whole map in a uniform way, so streams API might be useful here. However, the processing is so simple, that it might not worth it.

Comment: @Rick I want to use lambada and for that I need to convert the same into funtional style with context to above piece of code

Comment: Note that using lambdas (not lambada although that might get interesting ;) ) does not necessarily mean a functional style. A real functional style would need to address more, e.g. side effects.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use lambda you can do for example this:

```java
delMap.entrySet()
      .forEach(entry -> abcService.getsmartIds(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
delMap.forEach((abcId, list) -> {
   abcService.getsmartIds(abcId, list);
});
```

or simply

```java
delMap.forEach(abcService::getsmartIds);
```